# Windows Store App - C# - DataContext Binding in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, datacontext

Is there a way I can bind the `DataContext` of a control directly to a Property of my page class?

At the moment I am doing it like this.

MainPage.xaml

```
        ...

        <controls:NcButton x:Name="signal"  Icon="{Binding ConnectedIcon}" MainColour="{Binding ConnectedColour}" >
            <controls:NcButton.DataContext>
                <Nervecentre:SessionInfo />
            </controls:NcButton.DataContext>
        </controls:NcButton>

        ...
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    ...

    public SessionInfo SessionState
    {
        get { return Session.SessionState; }
    }

    ...

    public MainPage()
    {
        ...

        // Set the data bindings
        signal.DataContext = SessionState;

        ...
    }

    ...
```

What I would like to do is something like

```
        ...

        <controls:NcButton x:Name="signal"  Icon="{Binding ConnectedIcon}" MainColour="{Binding ConnectedColour}" DataContext="{Binding Source=SessionState}"/>

        ...
```

So I don't have to assign the my `SessionInfo` object to the `DataContext` in the contrusctor..

Comment: Where are your other properties like ConnectedIcon coming from?

Comment: They come from the `SessionInfo` class. I haven't posted the code, as it's a bit beyond the scope of the question. The above code snippets have the desired effect. I would rather, and would have thought it possible, to bind the `DataContext` to a property in `MainPage` class.